# Start reindexing programmatically

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

We have a screen in our web application where the user can select a list of XPaths for which he wants to create Path range indexes.

We are looking for a way to start reindexing by using REST/Java/XQuery(auto reindexing is disabled). this reindexing will be triggered when the user clicks on the Reindex button provided in my web application.

We are using MarkLogic v10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to call the Management REST endpoint to kick off a reindex:

[https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]#ReindexDB](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v2/databases/%5Bid-or-name%5D#ReindexDB)

Alternatively, you could enable automatic-reindexing prior to adding the new indexes:

[https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/databases/%5Bid-or-name%5D/properties)